# Удаление элемента по индексу Angular 4

Tags: angular2

Данным кодом удаляю объект на сервере.

```
private deleteTask(taskId: number) {        

    this.serv.deleteTask(taskId).subscribe(data => {
        if (data.status) {
            let index = this.tasks.indexOf(taskId);
            this.tasks.splice(index, 1);              
        }
    },
        error => console.log(error)
    );
}
```

И хочу удалить строку(элемент В DOM) по index во View. Но студия ругается на `indexOf(taskId)` и пишет :

> Error TS2345  (TS) Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'Task'

```
 let index = this.tasks.indexOf((taskId: number)); но не помогло.
```

Как удалить элемент по индексу?

Comment: Возможно стоит заменить обе строчки внутри `if` на `this.tasks = this.tasks.filter(task => task.id !== taskId)`

Comment: Так получилось =)

Comment: Пишите ответ значит)

Comment: А, если не секрет, что ты за приложение пишешь?)

Comment: @diraria Уже написал. Тестовое )) Осталось с форматом даты разобраться https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/726944/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-angular-4 =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таком виде работает

```
 if (data.status) {
            this.tasks = this.tasks.filter(task => task.id !== taskId);                
        }
```