# Формат даты Angular 4

Tags: angular2

Почему формат даты не меняется. Подключил все как в документации [Angular.io](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

app.component.ts

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
providers: [HttpService, DatePipe]  
})

@NgModule({   
    providers: [DatePipe, CommonModule]
})
```

В моделе так

```
datestart: Date;
dateend: Date;
```

Во вьюхе так:

```
 <td>{{task.dateStart | date :'short'}}</td>
 <td>{{task.dateEnd | date}}</td>
```

Но формат не меняется и представляет собой `2017-10-04T19:26:02.3594309`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен. Пересобрал проект и заработало